# Как реализовать прикрепление файла в сообщениях?

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать прикрепление файла в сообщениях, используя jquery + php?

Спасибо.

Comment: Очень информативно, в каких таких сообщениях?

Comment: для этого необходимо в форме добавить поле input[type="file"] + обработчик

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, будет полезно http://habrahabr.ru/post/71772/